# Reading UIEE dataset into R data frame

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe

The UIEE functional spec (reference [1] at the foot of this) shows an example record as below. There must be a straightforward way to get this into an 'R' data frame but I can't find anything that deals with it. (Note that each field is on a new line and the clearly the record spans a variable number of lines.)

1. what would be the (intuitively) most appropriate structure for this in R?
2. what is the easiest way to achieve that in R?

Example record:

```
UR|MYBOOKS000552<br>
TI|The Missions of New Mexico, 1776<br>
AA|Adams, Eleanor B. and Chavez, Angelico<br>
CN|Very fine w/fine dj<br>
PP|Albuquerque<br>
DP|1956<br>
NC|Well-preserved, excellent binding, good color in dj.<br>
MT|American History<br>
KE|Architecture<br>
KE|New Mexico<br>
KE|Religion<br>
KE|Western Americana<br>
LG|eng<br>
WT|18<br>
PR|145.00<br>
XA|4<br>
XB|1<br>
XC|BO<br>
XD|S<br>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Refs:
[1] http://www.uiee.com/page2.htm

Comment: So each record should have columns UR, TI, AA...?